# WordPress + Easy FancyBox = d.onCleanup is not a function

Tags: wordpress

Hi Guys I have a problem similar to [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468348/fancybox-d-oncleanup-is-not-a-function) but based on WordPress.

Everything was working fine, then the plugin has stopped to work! I am no more able to load my modal windows because the plugin is not able to load the CSS.

The fact is that I've tryed to  unistall and install a brand new version of the plugin a coupple of times, but noting has changed, I still see this error:

```
d.onCleanup is not a function
```

from the file *wp-content/plugins/easy-fancybox/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js?ver=1.3.4*

Now I've seen that I sould check for the css file created by *easy-fancybox.css.php* and when I try what's is inside this file I've a 404 Nothing Found error, but the file is present inside my folder and I really don't understand why its behaving like that!

I've cheched permissions, copied a coupple of times but nothing solved my problem!

Someone has a clue on how to fix this issue?

If you wanna see the site [follow this link](http://designonsale.info/wordpress/prodotti/) and click on a thumbnail.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Just add fancybox js and css like below.

```
add_action('init','jsregister');

function jsregister(){
wp_register_script( 'fb', WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/fancybox/fancy/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js','jquery', false );

wp_enqueue_script( 'fb' );

wp_register_script( 'fbe', WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/fancybox/fancy/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js','jquery', false );

wp_enqueue_script( 'fbe' );

wp_register_style('fbs', WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/fancybox/fancy/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css');
wp_enqueue_style( 'fbs');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you're long past this, but as it came up for me, I'll present what worked for me, namely Turn off Super-cache or whatever cache type plugin you might have running (make sure the cache files are gone too.)  Everything went back to normal for me after that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your WP installation in the site root catches the call to http://designonsale.info/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/easy-fancybox/easy-fancybox.css.php?ver=1.3.4 before it reaches the actual file.

Is there some .htaccess rule doing that maybe?