# Unable to get fancybox 1.3.4 to work

Tags: jquery, asp.net, fancybox

I'm trying to work with fancybox 1.3.4.
All it's doing is giving me an error.

**Error**:

`d.onCleanup is not a function`

If the error doesn't come, just open the image in a new tab.
I followed the examples on the homepage as much as I could.

**Code**:

HTML:

```
<a class="grouped_elements" rel="ppt1" href="/static/images/bermuda/powerpoint/1_b.jpg"><img src="/static/images/bermuda/powerpoint/1_b.jpg" /></a>
<a class="grouped_elements" rel="ppt1"><img src="/static/images/bermuda/powerpoint/2_b.jpg" /></a>
<a class="grouped_elements" rel="ppt1"><img src="/static/images/bermuda/powerpoint/3_b.jpg" /></a>
<a class="grouped_elements" rel="ppt1"><img src="/static/images/bermuda/powerpoint/4_b.jpg" /></a>
<a class="grouped_elements" rel="ppt1"><img src="/static/images/bermuda/powerpoint/5_b.jpg" /></a>
```

Jquery:
masterpage:
`<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>`

aspx:
this is in the top.
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />`

This is in my document.ready
`$('a.grouped_elements').fancybox();`

Yes I did notice only the first `<a>` has the `href` attribute but it's just for testing.

**Edit**:

It doesn't open in a new tab it just goes to that image(so a blank page with that image)
and when I return to the page with all pictures on it the click won't work at all.

Comment: Are you also including the jquery core? This is required in addition to the fancybox...js include.

Comment: yes I am. Thought it was kinda obvious thats why I didnt paste it into the question ;)

Comment: are you using drupal? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468348/fancybox-d-oncleanup-is-not-a-function

Comment: I have no idea what drupal is but the link has helped. to bad I cant accept it as answer :(
Problem solved, it had to do with the css link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the answer is:

```
it's the problem with CSS. After you changed link to CSS it seems to be fixed.
```

btw. very strange problem :/ i don't understand how it could be related

Comment: Well it I just made a typo in the destination path of the CSS file.
Your link made me check my link twice so I found the typo ;)

Comment: Wow, it's so weird that this was the problem.  Why would lack of CSS cause JS to fail?