# FancyBox loader image always displays

Tags: jquery, wordpress, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have loaded the appropriate fancybox script and the stylesheet, and initialized the simplest version of fancy box that I can.  I have never had this problem before, and the code works fine in a JSfiddle, but this time I get the loading icon appearing right smack in the middle of the page, before any fancy boxes are intentionally triggered.

http://www.michaladarling.com/

And then when I click on the small thumbnails at the bottom to launch the fancy box, I get an error in my console that reads:

Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'onCleanup'

Something small must be off and I just can't see it.

Comment: The WordPress theme I was using was preferentially loading its version of FancyBox which is the older version 1 and not the newer version 2.

Comment: Voting for clsoe. Please don't ask SO users to browse your site and find errors. First try to do some debugging by yourself, then extract not-working snippet from your code and then ask question here providing proper piece of code.

Comment: Apologies Peter, I know the question is a bit thin, but SO is my place of last resort and I tried a lot of things before posting, sometimes there isn't code to post. I needed to show the incorrect loader and I always ask people I help with WordPress to provide a URL, so it seemed pertinent.  The question isn't as localized as I thought as JFK's answer provided a link that explains the error code I received as a mismatch between Fancybox assets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"***...I get the loading icon appearing right smack in the middle of the page, before any fancy boxes are intentionally triggered.***"

That is not the fancybox's loading icon but nivoslider's loading icon. **[Check here](http://www.michaladarling.com/wp-content/themes/clean/images/nivo-slider/loading.gif)**.

---

***"...I get an error in my console that reads: "***

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'onCleanup'
```

That error is generated when the fancybox css file is missing as you can **[see it here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4468348/1055987)**.

In your specific case, you are using the **[fancybox v2.1.4 css file](http://www.michaladarling.com/wp-content/themes/clean-child/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css)** with the **[fancybox v2.1.3 js file](http://www.michaladarling.com/wp-content/themes/clean-child/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js)** ... so there is a version mismatch.

Just upgrade the fancybox js file to v2.1.4

Comment: Thanks for the explanations.  I was actually seeing: http://www.michaladarling.com/wp-content/themes/clean-child/js/fancybox/fancybox_loading.gif so the fancybox loader.  The problem was as you described, my WordPress theme was loading the wrong script (v1.something).